# Whatsapp sticker appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, whatsapp, titanium-modules

I want to creat an stickers application using appcelerator platform , my question is how can i share my stickers to whatsapp there’s any module support ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that with Appcelerator. Have a look at the native example app at https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/